# How to clean up Django login message from framework

Tags: python, django

There is a project setup with **Django 1.6** and **Django allauth**. when user logged in django saves a login message to users session and its stack in there. While user reached to any page included messages framework, login message shows up with other message.

Because of this reason, **I want to remove login message from message queue after user logged in.**

I tried remove login message in *django*'s and *allauth*'s `user_logged_in` *signal*, but I discovered the message is not created there.

The example of the message removal code is below:

```
# from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in
# First I tried allauth signal above.
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_(request, **kwargs):
    storage = messages.get_messages(request)
    storage.used = True
```

**Edit:** The workaround below is working. But I feel it is not right way to do.

<s>After this, I decided to make a workaround. After user logged in, user redirected to index view. I removed signal and append `storage.used = True` method in *index view*. Also It is not worked too.</s>

```
def clear_messages(request):
    storage = messages.get_messages(request)
    storage.used = True


def index(request):
    clear_messages(request)
    return render_to_response('website/index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request, {}))
```

Comment: You have to set storage.used = True

Comment: Yes, I did the correction after I discovered my stupidity :) But It is not worked either. Logout message is removed but login message is still displaying.

Comment: You are not returning a request context instance. Use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render).

Comment: Is it related with the issue? Because a simple context is exists in the original code.

Answer (score 12):

From [django-allauth's documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#messages):

> All messages (as in django.contrib.messages) are configurable by
>   overriding their respective template. If you want to disable a message
>   simply override the message template with a blank one.

Comment: i was able to achieve this (in practice) by creating 2 empty files `templates/account/messages/logged_in.txt` and `templates/account/messages/logged_out.txt `.

Comment: @psychok7 this worked for me too, but I have no idea why. Does anyone have any official documentation on this? 

Comment: The "2 empty files" approach works for me as well, but you're basically disabling one functionality (login messages) to enable another (in my case form submit messages). Any other alternatives??

Comment: @psychok7 but it's not perfect solution.. in my case user can login using any link.. which generated by system.. and redirect them to requested link not specific view or screen.. and it's not working in  my case..

Answer (score 1):

This answer merely fleshes out psychok7's comment to Paulo Almeida's answer.

To disable a message, you can override the django-allauth message *.txt* template with a blank version.

For example: Assuming you have a central templates dir (say, in the project's root directory) called 'templates', you would add a *logged_in.txt* file at the following location:
`templates/account/messages/logged_in.txt`. If that template has no content, then the message which is normally presented after a successful login will not be displayed. Ditto for the other messages that django-allauth uses.

The django-allauth templates that can be overridden/disabled in this way are found at
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/main/allauth/templates/account/messages